# Firebase update apple-app-site-association

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am implementing dynamic links and everything works well, besides that in my project settings I changed the "Team ID" aka "AppStore App Prefix".

If I visit `myproject.page.link/apple-app-site-association` it still is giving me the old team ID and I am worrying that could break dynamic links later when the App is being released.

Does it take time to be updated? Or is there a way for me to force a refresh of the values?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there also a way to customize the paths in this file when using a firebase page.link domain?

Comment: Are you on mac? Did you happen to name the file `apple-app-site-association.json` and then change it to `apple-app-site-association`? I did this and good old macOS didn't change the actual file name, keeping the `.json` under the covers & preventing the file from being named correctly. I had to delete the file and re-create it with the right name, then everything worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is cached, so can take some time. If you're still seeing it after a day, please file a ticket with Firebase support who can route it through to the Dynamic Links team: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/?category=troubleshooting

Comment: Taking up to a day to update a flat file on the web is not acceptable. support ticket filed...

Comment: I updated a bundle identifier by creating a new app in the same Firebase project, and the dynamic link isn't working in the new bundle id, but it worked in the older bundle id. I updated everything, and still no luck in the new one. the dynamic link with apple-app-site-association returns both the old and the new bundle ids, but the new bundle id one , the app is not opened. Website gets opened instead with "Invalid Dynamic Link". Hopefully this is just a caching issue, I will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Just try to add a new URL prefix, that worked for us

Comment: @MohsenEsmaeili I add new URL prefix and indeed the new URL prefix has the correct apple-app-site-association. The problem is we want to use the existing URL prefix. I tried to delete the existing URL prefix, but Firebase warns us that we won't be able to reclaim the prefix for a month. That's unacceptable. So we cancel the deletion. But the apple-app-site-association doesn't refresh either. So we're stuck.

Answer (score 15):

This usually happens when you create the URL prefix before adding all the required information (Team ID, Appstore ID, Support Email). in this case the apple-app-site-association file will remain empty for long time and maybe never updates. to resolve this add all the required information then add a new URL prefix and you will get immediately a correct apple-app-site-association file for the new URL. hope that helps

Comment: I created a dynamic link for Android and got it working. Then, for iOS, once I updated my Appstore ID and Team ID in Firebase project settings it didn't take long for the apple-app-site-association URL to update.

Comment: @Lucy yes this is the normal behaviour, however, probably due to a bug in firebase, it fails quite often.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I deleted an iOS app from my Firebase project and created a new one. The AASA (apple-app-site-association) file was showing both the old and the new app listings and this caused my dynamic links to be broken. I reached out to Firebase support and this was their answer:

*Just an overview, your AASA file is tied with your project’s OAuth Client IDs. These OAuth Client IDs are created when an app is added to a project and not necessarily deleted when you delete or edit your app on the Firebase dashboard, and can consequently cause issues with the AASA's app listing. If this is the case and you have deleted or modified this app before the issue occur, you'll need to manually delete the associated OAuth Client ID/s in the Google Cloud Console in order for it to be removed in your AASA file. You can do this by following the steps below:*

- *Go to the [API Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).*
- *Select your project.*
- *Delete the OAuth 2.0 Client ID for the incorrect Bundle ID*
- *Allow for an hour to pass and check your AASA to see if it has updated.*

This worked for me!