# iOS app deeplinks and Firebase dynamic links don't work after app transfer

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I've transferred my iOS app from one developer to another. Then after first release at new account, my deeplinks accidentally stop working.

Deeplinks implemented using universal links on my own hosted url and firebase dynamic links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that my Team ID changed after transfer.

---

1. In case of universal links on self hosted url, I had to update my `apple-app-site-association` file, because it contains old id.

**Example:**

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "{TEAM_ID}.{BUNDLE_ID}",
        "paths": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

2. In case of firebase dynamic links, I had to change my Team ID in project settings. Then to make them update `apple-app-site-association` file for your links you have to contact support.

**[Reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828627/4950794)**

> It is cached, so can take some time. If you're still seeing it after a
>   day, please file a ticket with Firebase support who can route it
>   through to the Dynamic Links team:
>   https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/?category=troubleshooting

---

**UPD:**

I've got response from support and everything is working, hope my answer helps someone!

> Hi Abzal,
>
> Andy here, and I noticed that you've recently updated your
>   iOS app's Team ID.   Once this is updated in the Firebase settings, it
>   can take a few minutes for the AASA file to reflect the latest
>   changes.
>
> Please check this on your end if the AASA file is now
>   up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can add that now (25/05/2021) after changing the TeamId in Firebase after 30 minutes the json was already updated.